# openerTabId in Chrome changed to undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple Chrome extension which tells the `openerTabId` of the active tab.

It works as excepted at first. But when I create a new tab and switch back to old tabs, all old tabs' `openerTabId` turns to `undefined`

Here's my code:

```
/////////////////////// popup.js ///////////////////////
'use strict';

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    for(var i=0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
      alert(tabs[i].id + ": opened from: " + tabs[i].openerTabId);
    }
});

/////////////////////// popup.html ///////////////////////
<script src="popup.js"></script>

/////////////////////// manifest.json ///////////////////////
{
  "name": "TabTest",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. open a tab, navigate to any website
2. click any link in the tab to open a child tab `t1`
3. click the browser action button to check the child tab's `openerTabId` `id1`
4. open a new blank tab
5. switch back to tab `t1`, click the browser action button to check the child tab's `openerTabId` `id2`
6. find that `id1 != id2 && id2 is undefined`

Any tips to the reason or any other reliable way to get a tab's parent?

Comment: You'll have to listen to chrome.tabs.onCreated and store the openerTabId in a local object/map.

Comment: https://crbug.com/967150

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for mentioning the bug. I notice there are some extensions such as [Sidewise Tree Style Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sidewise-tree-style-tabs/biiammgklaefagjclmnlialkmaemifgo) can get the parent-child relation of tabs opened before installing the extension. Do you know how they do this?

Comment: I don't know. I guess it works only until a new tab is opened. You can inspect its source code yourself in devtools or in an IDE.